# Try Catch block in php 5.3.5 not working

Tags: php, try-catch

Well I have a WampServer installed on my WinXP box with PHP 3.5.3 and apache 2.2.17. Strangely the try catch block doesnt work, after some googling I could only find that the bug lies in eaccelerator (but phpinfo showed no trace of it).

where am i going wrong??

```
try{
echo "from try";
parent::conect();
}catch(Exception $e){
echo "from catch";}
```

My output should be

```
from tryfrom catch
```

But instead i get

```
from try
Fatal Error: cannot access parent:: when no class...
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're not expecting try/catch to work from thin air. Where's your code?

Comment: Can't reproduce, works for me. You'll need to give us a lot more detail.

Comment: @deceze... what all do you need besides code?

Comment: @all why am i getting dug down??

Answer (score 1):

> Notice: Undefined variable: a in blah on line 4

This is not an exception. It is an error message. Or more specifically a notice,  which classifies as debug message.

Try/Catch will not capture them in a default PHP setup. You would need an error [handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) which converts them into an exception. But that would be stupid.

In your case you should just define your variable beforehand. (In a few other cases you would test it with [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset)).

```
$a = 0;
try {
   echo "from try";
   $a+=1;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
   echo "from catch";
}
```

The try/catch is redundant then. Neither `echo` nor the `+` operation will trigger an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Notice is not Exception. You can not catch it by try catch.